# How does the not symbol affect this formula?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm trying to understand what

$\lnot x < y$

would mean. Is it that x is not less than y?

Comment: What ware x and y? Real numbers? Without context i would interpret that as x is more or equal to y.

Comment: They are either real numbers or integers. It's a part of a formula; I'm trying to figure out if the formula is true on Z and/or R.

Comment: Are you sure its not $\lnot (x < y)$

Comment: Well the formula is:

$\forall x \; \exists y \;(y < x \land \forall z \;(z < x \rightarrow \lnot \;y < z))$

Comment: @123412523562: The part $\neg y<z$ is to be understood as $\neg(y<z)$, i.e., as $y\not< z$.

Comment: The *negation* sign : $\lnot$ is a *connective* that "acts" on *formulae* (that represent statements) and not on *variables* (that represent "names" of objects). Thus, there is only one way to "read" it : $\lnot (x < y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x<y$ means that $x$ is less than $y$ and $\neg$, as you know, is the symbol for "negation", the formula $\neg(x<y)$ means that it's not the case that $x$ is less than $y$. Equivalently, this means that $x$ is at least as big as $y$:
$$x\geq y$$